# Who is the person in this artwork?

Tags: painting

Who is the person in the picture? I'm thinking he might be famous but I can't be sure...

[image]

Comment: Is this the correct place to post this question?

Comment: I'm afraid not - this is a site for *applied* art/crafts, not art history or identification. Have a look at the [help/on-topic] page for a more in depth list of what is or isn't on topic here.

Comment: Try using the image based search on Google... you search via a link to an image, the answer below is in the [hit results of a search of the url of your post.](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisKnwgd6Lz4IeIq4zHxugv5Jso4Ad0w2vP47A6wxllZ6KnLE9vj25VmSWME-DhYP78V6bZ2T6tYGsXf33Gj5cUd2kmngK6WF90AyKqGsGVpu24pStheK02ZmenxJPRIlJzoXzOHFdI0SC0RIM5b9LxbdhyKn8rUUXdO236McQACRrho1bx9KUed99xpOd31BzxWQSZ4_10R5e9kkjJfkcvu-qouYJMgVTqKW5MQLv2wxxTMbS4ybVoh6drdXB7QsNsiACigkNEXhn0aSoUGDibvZW1EROHbuOTUJgUBBl-pWhk6WdMHYMDCM-3WXSg0whzlNkCXX75BjBf2kPyaXqW7M6S-iBA&hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roy Lichtenstein, 'Roy I' by Chuck Close